# How can I recieve the root x509 certificate from a signed PDF file in java?

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox, digital-signature, x509certificate

I'm working on a PDF signature validation project with the DSS framework.
To properly verify a signature I need to recieve the signature's root certificate.
I can do it manually with Acrobat Reader DC, but i need to automate the whole process.

I tried to use PDFBox, iText, and the DSS framework too but I cannot find any methods that returns the X509 certificate. If I can found the cert, I need to write it into a .cer file from the cert's byte array. So the validation process can work with it.

I tried to automate the Acrobat Reader DC with Robot Framework, but it isn't dynamic.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

I need to use the certificate here:

```
CertificateSource certSource = new CommonTrustedCertificateSource();
certSource.addCertificate(DSSUtils.loadCertificate(cert)); //the cert must be the certificate(it's file or byteArray)
```

Digital Signature Services documentation: https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html

Comment: PDFBox doesn't have such a feature out of the box, but the `ShowSignature.java` example in PDFBox validates certificates up to the root.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I need to validate the certificates with the DSS framework and I can do that with it. The problem is that, at the start of the whole validation process I need to add the signature's root certificate to validate the signature properly. Now I had manually exported it from the Acrobat Reader, but the thing is I need to do that process automated and validate every signature with it's own root certificate.

Comment: Look at `SigUtils.verifyCertificateChain()` which prepares a call to  `CertificateVerifier.verifyCertificate()` which returns a `PKIXCertPathBuilderResult` object, from which you can get the root by calling `getTrustAnchor()`.

Comment: Why do you need to add it while Adobe Reader apparently has it already?